# I came here vs. I went there

Tags: adverbs

I corrected a piece of writing for a friend recently and stumbled over something he wrote.

He did a review of a place he once visited (no pictures of the place provided) and wrote: "I came here for celebrating..., etc."

It sounds strange to me to use "here" when it is used in written language but I don´t know for sure. Shouldn´t it be "I went there" since no picture of the place is provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is where you friend was located, either physically or mentally, when he wrote his review.

If, for instance, he uploaded a picture of himself (although you say he didn't) it would be quite clear that he was positioning himself at the place concerned.

But even without the picture, it's quite possible and legitimate for him to imagine that he's writing the review from that location.

The basic principle is that:

> you come here (to where the writer/speaker is located)

and

> you go there (to where-ever the writer speaker refers you).

But within that guide there's lots of room for using *come* or *go*.

For example, if you are in London and you are planning to meet a friend who is stationed in Berlin, you could say either:

> Come to Paris where I'll meet you next week

as Paris is closer to London than Berlin

or

> Go to Paris where I'll meet you next week.

It's a question of nuance, geography and context.